# Cmd can't find file

Tags: go, cmd

I am attempting to minimize files using cmd.

The code:

```
func minify(path string) {
    if exists(path) {
        fmt.Println("File exist")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("File NOT exist")
    }

    cmdStr := `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\\n//g' ` + path + " > " + path
    fmt.Println(cmdStr)
    cmd := exec.Command(cmdStr)
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func exists(name string) bool {
    if _, err := os.Stat(name); err != nil {
        if os.IsNotExist(err) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

The function exist() verifies that the file exists:

```
2021/04/20 14:14:53 /media/peter/Elements/Code/free-quotes.info/ubuntu/aws/Go/views/500.min.html
File exist
```

But when trying to run the command `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\\n//g' /media/peter/Elements/Code/free-quotes.info/ubuntu/aws/Go/views/500.min.html > /media/peter/Elements/Code/free-quotes.info/ubuntu/aws/Go/views/500.min.html`

I get `no such file or directory`

Based on feedback below I tried

```
func minify(oldPath string, newPath string) {
    cmd := exec.Command("sed", ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g", oldPath, ">", newPath)
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(whereami.WhereAmI(), err)
    }
}
```

But now I get:

```
File: main.go  Function: main.minify Line: 91 exit status 1
```

Comment: The command is just `sed`, not the entire line with arguments. You re also not executing a shell, so sell redirection like `>` wouldn't work either. If you want to execute a shell script, pass it as an argument to a shell.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove all newlines, you can just use Go directly:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   b, e := os.ReadFile("file.txt")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   b = bytes.ReplaceAll(b, []byte{'\n'}, nil)
   println(string(b))
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/bytes#ReplaceAll

Answer (score 0):

You are passing all parts including path and arguments in one single argument. However, when you look at Command function, it requires path and arguments seperately as it is stated in the following document. https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command

So I believe you should edit your code like below;
exec.Command("sed", ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g", fPath1, ">", fPath2)

Comment: `>` is not a valid argument, it’s an output redirection for a shell.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've realised my mistake after I'd seen your comment which you have made to the question.